# Yocto, bitbake - how to remove unwanted hunks in the patch file

Tags: diff, yocto, patch, bitbake

I am trying to bitbake system for seedStudio odyssey board. I got into problems applying patches

```
CmdError('quilt --quiltrc /home/seed-studio/STM/Distribution-Package/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/stm32mp1-ostl-linux-gnueabi/optee-os-stm32mp/3.19.0-stm32mp-r1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/etc/quiltrc push', 0, "stdout: Applying patch 0001-Add-stm32mp157c-odyssey.dts-to-support-odyssey-npi-s.patch
patching file core/arch/arm/dts/stm32mp15-pinctrl.dtsi
patching file core/arch/arm/dts/stm32mp151.dtsi
patching file core/arch/arm/dts/stm32mp157c-odyssey.dts
patching file core/arch/arm/dts/stm32mp157c-odyssey.dtsi
The next patch would create the file lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-Bold.ttf,
which already exists!  Applying it anyway.
File lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-Bold.ttf: git binary diffs are not supported.
The next patch would create the file lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-BoldItalic.ttf,
which already exists!  Applying it anyway.
File lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-BoldItalic.ttf: git binary diffs are not supported.
The next patch would create the file lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-Italic.ttf,
which already exists!  Applying it anyway.
File lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-Italic.ttf: git binary diffs are not supported.
The next patch would create the file lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-Light.ttf,
which already exists!  Applying it anyway.
File lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-Light.ttf: git binary diffs are not supported.
The next patch would create the file lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-LightCondensed.ttf,
which already exists!  Applying it anyway.
File lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-LightCondensed.ttf: git binary diffs are not supported.
The next patch would create the file lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-LightCondensedItalic.ttf,
which already exists!  Applying it anyway.
File lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-LightCondensedItalic.ttf: git binary diffs are not supported.
The next patch would create the file lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-LightItalic.ttf,
which already exists!  Applying it anyway.
File lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-LightItalic.ttf: git binary diffs are not supported.
The next patch would create the file lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-Regular.ttf,
which already exists!  Applying it anyway.
File lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Amble-Regular.ttf: git binary diffs are not supported.
The next patch would create the file 'lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Apache License.txt',
which already exists!  Applying it anyway.
patching file 'lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Apache License.txt'
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- rejects in file 'lib/libutee/tui/fonts/amble/Apache License.txt'
Patch 0001-Add-stm32mp157c-odyssey.dts-to-support-odyssey-npi-s.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
```

1. I would like to not use some hunks. Do I have to manually edit the patch file?
2. Is there any "user friendly" tool to remove hunks from the patch file?